# Django Title Block Showing on Page Content

Tags: python, django

example of issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfbEK.jpg

**Code**

views.py

```
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
context = {
    "title" : "PortfolioLog - Home",
    
}
return render(request, "base.html", context)
```

base.html

```
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{{title}}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Home page">
        {% load static %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'scripts.js' %}"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem? You are passing a string in the context with key 'title'. Then, in the 'base.html' you insert the {{title}} which calls the context key in the <title>. Improve your question please.

Comment: @DivertingPie Check the link listed to the image. For some reason, it prints the title like a <p>. I am not sure why, it does make the change to the actual <title> tag which I am happy about but I do not want it to print the title as text additionally.

Comment: Probably it happens, because you don't have `<body>`? Your browser does its best to show at least something.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

My styles.css was displaying all elements, therefore the title element, as
display: block;

Fixed it by changing it to title {display: none;}